# Using a Javascript variable as an index of EJS Array - NODEJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

**Here is my Jquery Code**

```
$(document).on("click", "a.icons", function() {
                    var eventId = $(this).data('id');
                    var patientName =  "<%= patients_list["+eventId+"].full_name%>";
                    $('#idHolder').html(patientName);

                });
```

What I want is to use a Javascript variable as an index of EJS Array?

**Any help would be highly appreciated.**

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: did you try it ?

Comment: Yes I tried it @MrJ

Comment: It shows full_name is not defined

Comment: How can you imagine that we can answer you with the presentation of so little code ? !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your EJS array to a JS array:

```
// Create a JS variable and assign your EJS variable value
var patients_list = <%- JSON.stringify(patients_list) %>;
$(document).on("click", "a.icons", function() {
  var eventId = $(this).data('id');
  var patientName =  patients_list[eventId].full_name;
  $('#idHolder').html(patientName);
});
```